# Focus Lab's EE Master Config under webroot

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

What Focus Lab’s EE Master Config modifications are required for `/config/config.master.php` to work within webroot (eg. `public_html` or `htdocs`), if I cannot place it *above* webroot?

The instructions provided on their [github](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) page are for placement above webroot.   It has a link to a step-by-step article regarding placing it within webroot by Alex Ball, but the link does not resolve.

Comment: What kind of errors are you encountering? Are you following the readme on their github page? https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config

Comment: Thanks Nuno, I have updated the question.  I'm seeing a   white page in the CP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but in the interest of sharing…

I have discovered that the required modification to use Focus Lab’s EE Master Config under your webroot folder (eg. `public_html` or `htdocs` folder) is simply a path update within `/config/config.master.php` on line 234 (version 1.1).

This should be the relative path to your `config.{env}.php` files.

Note that the same path update is required under your modified `config.php` and `database.php` files.