# Focuslab Master Config not working with MAMP

Tags: focus-lab-master-config

I have recently set up an ExpressionEngine 'Sandbox' test site locally via MAMP (On Mac OSX), and have integrated the Focus Lab LLC’s EE Master Config for when I push the local Sandbox site code to a staging server (using version control via Git/Tower/Beanstalk etc).

I have set up all the configurations as required using the documentation for Focus Lab LLC’s EE Master Config.

The issue:

When I naivgate to the local MAMP Sandbox site URL: 
ie. `http://localhost:8888/sandbox/`

I get the following server error message(s):

```
Warning: require(/Users/karlbowers/Sites/../config/config.master.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/karlbowers/Sites/Sandbox/system/expressionengine/config/config.php on line 410

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/Users/karlbowers/Sites/../config/config.master.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php') in /Users/karlbowers/Sites/Sandbox/system/expressionengine/config/config.php on line 410
```

I have placed the new 'config' folder at the same level as the 'system' folder.

ie.

```
public_html

  config
  system
  themes
```

etc.

I have added the following into my master config file:

```
if ( ! defined('ENV'))
{
    switch (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {

        case 'sandbox.domainname.co.uk' :
            define('ENV', 'stage');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Staging');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', FALSE);
        break;

        case 'localhost:8888/sandbox' :
            define('ENV', 'dev');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Development');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', TRUE);
        break;

        default :
            define('ENV', 'local');
            define('ENV_FULL', 'Local');
            define('ENV_DEBUG', TRUE);
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why I am getting the errors stated above?
It's like the URL paths are incorrect?

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Many thanks in advance.

Regards

Karl

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're running the system below webroot, which is not how the FocusLab master config is setup to run by default. From the readme:

> The instructions above are for setting up the config above webroot (your "public_html, "htdocs", etc directory).

So it assumes this structure:

```
/config
/httpdocs
/system
```

If you really need to run your system folder below webroot, [see this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13731/focus-labs-ee-master-config-under-webroot) - specifically, you need to change the include paths in /config/config.master.php and /system/expressionegine/config.php.

Comment: Hi Derek, (apologies for the long delayed response!). As per your suggestion (and Focuslab Docs) I have tried moving the 'config' & 'system' folder above root as suggested but it still does not seem to work? I tried this on both the local MAMP server and on my staging server set up. Any ideas what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Your switch/case statement is checking against `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` - so for your localhost, this would be `localhost`, not `localhost/folder-name`.

Typically, with this kind of setup, "development" and/or "staging" would be referring to a remote server - your localhost should instead fall under the final default case for local environments. This allows you to use either "localhost" or a named vhost (eg, "http://project.dev").